# Copying the Postgres directory via Samba?

Tags: samba, postgresql

I have Samba and Postgres installed on two machines.

I can successfully copy files from one machine to another when fhe files' user and group are my sign-in user and group for both machines. (The same sign in and password on both machines.)

My target directory, /mnt/pg-ralph12/, has been successfully mounted.

```
mount: //192.168.29.205/pg-ralph12 mounted on /mnt/pg-ralph12
```

The user and group for my Postgres directory on my source machine is:

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/postgresql
# owner: postgres
# group: postgres
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

For my target directory it's

```
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main
# owner: real-owner
# group: sudo
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:postgres:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:postgres:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

When I attempt to run rsync

```
sudo rsync -a /var/lib/postgresql /mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main
```

I get

```
[sudo] password for real-estate-data-mining: 
rsync: chown "/mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main/postgresql" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: chown "/mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main/postgresql/9.6" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: chown "/mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main/postgresql/9.6/main" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: chown "/mnt/pg-ralph12/not-main/postgresql/9.6/main/base" failed: Permission denied (13)
etc
```

I've searched high and low on the 'Net trying to find an answer with no success.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/364709/how-to-keep-rsync-from-chowning-transfered-files Sometimes it pays to also search left and right :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copy/replace myDatabase from Ralph07 to Ralph12

dropdb -e -h 192.168.29.205 --no-password --if-exists -U postgres myDatabase
# createdb -e -h 192.168.29.205 --no-password -U postgres myDatabase # The database will automagically be created
pg_dump -C -h localhost --no-password -U postgres myDatabase | psql -h 192.168.29.205 --no-password -U postgres
```

192.168.29.205 is the (static) ip address of the target computer. Your ip will likely be different.

In order to get the --no-password option to work, you'll have to edit ~/.pgpass. Mine (edited!) looks like the following:

```
localhost:5432:*:postgres:MyPassword
192.168.29.205:5432:*:postgres:MyPassword
```

See, for instance, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-pgpass.html for an explanation of .pgpass

You'll probably also need to edit /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf (if you're using 9.6 of Postgres).  See https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html

This solution seems to be robust.  I've had no trouble with it in the short time I've been using it (less than a day).  If I run into problems, I'll report it here.

Other solutions I've seen online to drop the database (i.e. going into psql) did not work for me.

### What did _not_ work for me

For reference, the following did NOT work for me to drop the database.

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'myDatabase';
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'myDatabase' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
DROP DATABASE "myDatabase";
```

I get the error "ERROR:  cannot drop the currently open database"

### Further question:

What's the difference between **dropdb** and the code immediately above?